# リストの入れ子から任意の値を取り出す

Tags: python

```
l = [(5,6),7,8,9]
```

というリストから6という値を取り出したい場合、どうすればいいのでしょうか?

```
print l[0:1]
```

とすると `[(5,6)]` となりますし、
`l.index(6)` とすると `ValueError: 6 is not in list` となります

リストのリストからスライスして表示する場合はどうしたらよいのでしょう?

Comment: `print l[0][1]`とか

Comment: `((a,b), c, d, e) = tuple(l); print b`とか。スライスじゃないけど。

Comment: print l[0][1]まさしくこれです。
2つ目も驚きました。こういう使い方もできるんですね。

Comment: ２番目はtuple()を使う必要はなかったみたいです。`(a,b), c,d,e = l`で行けました。

Comment: 確認しました。tuple()なしでも同じ結果になりました。入れ子の中の値はひとまとまりという扱いでindexやcountでは使えないのですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 3):

`l[0]` が `(5,6)` という tuple ですので，これの2つめを見ればいいです．

```
print l[0][1]
# -> 6
```

あるいは（今回の使い方でこちらが望ましい状況は限られるかもしれませんが），tuple や list のたぐいは適当にばらして([sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences))くれます．

```
(x,y), *rest = l
print y
# -> 6
```

Comment: 長らく回答がついてなくて上がってたのを最近見かけたので community wiki で投稿します．

Answer (score 2):

`l[0:1]` は Python のスライス文で、ある値を取り出せることはできません。単なる `l = [(5, 6), 7, 8, 9]` から 6 を取得するのは、`l[0][1]` でよろしいです。

なお、リストやタプルや辞書型が混合するデータ構造から任意深度の要素を取得することなら、他の方法を必要はです。

例えば、あるリスト `l` の入れ子から、`l[a][b][c]...[x]` で要素を取り出したいが、インデックス `idxlist = [a, b, c, ..., x]` の数を事前にわからない状況となると、下記のような `for` 文を用いたらよろしいです

```
l = [(5,6),7,8,9]
idxlist = [0, 1]

found_element = l
for index in idxlist:
    found_element = found_element[index]
print found_element # 6
```

あるいは、[`reduce` 関数](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)でこうして作成するのも良いです。

```
print reduce(lambda obj, key: obj[key],
             idxlist,
             l)
```